# Entity framework query not returning correct results

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, t-sql, asp.net-core

I am trying to pass a raw sql join with entity framework on my web api. this is my api code.

```
namespace HannaOilAndGas2.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/mainview")]
    public class MainViewApi : Controller
    {

        private readonly ScadaContext _context;

        public MainViewApi(ScadaContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("allmainview")]
        public IEnumerable<Device> GetAllMainView()
        {

            return _context.Device.FromSql(
                "SELECT PD.RecId, D.Location, Round(PD.SPOT_FLOW_RATE,0), Round(PD.PREVIOUS_DAY_VOLUME,0)," +
                "Round(PD.LINE_PRESSURE,0), Round(PD.DIFFERENTIAL_PRESSURE,0), Round(PD.TEMPERATURE,0)," +
                "Round(PD.BATTERY_VOLTAGE,0) ROUND(PD.FCP,0), ROUND(PD.FTP,0) D.LAST_COMMUNICATION, D.LAST_COMMUNICATION_METHOD" +
                "FROM DEVICE D" +
                "JOIN POLL_DATA PD" +
                "ON D.HANNA_DEVICE_ID = PD.HANNA_DEVICE_ID").Where(x => x.MeterId != "HOGC%"); 
        }
```

my device model looks like this because all of these tables relate to device

```
namespace HannaOilAndGas2.Data
{
    public partial class Device
    {
        public Device()
        {
            DailyData = new HashSet<DailyData>();
            PollBattery = new HashSet<PollBattery>();
            PollDifferentialPressure = new HashSet<PollDifferentialPressure>();
            PollFcp = new HashSet<PollFcp>();
            PollFtp = new HashSet<PollFtp>();
            PollLinePressure = new HashSet<PollLinePressure>();
            PollPdVolume = new HashSet<PollPdVolume>();
            PollSpotFlowRate = new HashSet<PollSpotFlowRate>();
            PollTemperature = new HashSet<PollTemperature>();
            PollData = new HashSet<PollData>();
            ChokeHistory = new HashSet<ChokeHistory>();
            CommentsHistory = new HashSet<CommentsHistory>();
            ContractHourHistory = new HashSet<ContractHourHistory>();
            HourlyData = new HashSet<HourlyData>();
            MeterTubeSizeHistory = new HashSet<MeterTubeSizeHistory>();
            OrificeCoeffHistory = new HashSet<OrificeCoeffHistory>();
            PlateSizeHistory = new HashSet<PlateSizeHistory>();
            PollDataHistorical = new HashSet<PollDataHistorical>();
            ShutinHistory = new HashSet<ShutinHistory>();
        }

        public int HannaDeviceId { get; set; }
        public int? MdbDeviceId { get; set; }
        public string SpreadsheetId { get; set; }
        public string SpectraId { get; set; }
        public string ServiceStarId { get; set; }
        public string MeterId { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public float? ShutinPressure { get; set; }
        public float? Latitude { get; set; }
        public float? Longitude { get; set; }
        public float? Choke { get; set; }
        public float? OrificeCoeff { get; set; }
        public decimal? MeterTubeSize { get; set; }
        public float? ContractHour { get; set; }
        public string SecTwnRange { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public decimal? PlateSize { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastCommunication { get; set; }
        public string LastCommunicationMethod { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<DailyData> DailyData { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PollBattery> PollBattery { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PollDifferentialPressure> PollDifferentialPressure { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PollFcp> PollFcp { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PollFtp> PollFtp { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PollLinePressure> PollLinePressure { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PollPdVolume> PollPdVolume { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PollSpotFlowRate> PollSpotFlowRate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PollTemperature> PollTemperature { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PollData> PollData { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ChokeHistory> ChokeHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CommentsHistory> CommentsHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ContractHourHistory> ContractHourHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<HourlyData> HourlyData { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MeterTubeSizeHistory> MeterTubeSizeHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrificeCoeffHistory> OrificeCoeffHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PlateSizeHistory> PlateSizeHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PollDataHistorical> PollDataHistorical { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ShutinHistory> ShutinHistory { get; set; }

    }
}
```

this is my context

```
 public partial class ScadaContext : DbContext
    {
        public ScadaContext(DbContextOptions<ScadaContext> options) : base(options)
        {}

        public ScadaContext()
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ChokeHistory> ChokeHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CommentsHistory> CommentsHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ContractHourHistory> ContractHourHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DailyData> DailyData { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Device> Device { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<HourlyData> HourlyData { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<MeterTubeSizeHistory> MeterTubeSizeHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<OrificeCoeffHistory> OrificeCoeffHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PlateSizeHistory> PlateSizeHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PollBattery> PollBattery { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PollData> PollData { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PollDataHistorical> PollDataHistorical { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PollDifferentialPressure> PollDifferentialPressure { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PollFcp> PollFcp { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PollFtp> PollFtp { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PollLinePressure> PollLinePressure { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PollPdVolume> PollPdVolume { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PollSpotFlowRate> PollSpotFlowRate { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PollTemperature> PollTemperature { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ShutinHistory> ShutinHistory { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ChokeHistory>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.RecId)
                    .HasName("PK_CHOKE_HISTORY");

                entity.ToTable("CHOKE_HISTORY");

                entity.Property(e => e.RecId).HasColumnName("RecID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Choke).HasColumnName("CHOKE");

                entity.Property(e => e.HannaDeviceId).HasColumnName("HANNA_DEVICE_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.ImportMethod)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("IMPORT_METHOD")
                    .HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.Timestamp)
                    .HasColumnName("TIMESTAMP")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.HannaDevice)
                    .WithMany(p => p.ChokeHistory)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.HannaDeviceId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_CHOKE_HISTORY_DEVICE");
            });
```

all my tables are set up following this I would like to get the query in the api to work but all I get back is an empty result of []. I am fairly new to entity framework I have read that you could do raw sql like that. I am not sure what I am doing wrong any help would be appreciated. My app is a .net core 1.1 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of limitations to be aware of when using raw SQL queries:

- SQL queries can only be used to return entity types that are part of
  your model. There is an enhancement on our backlog to enable
  returning ad-hoc types from raw SQL queries.
- The SQL query must return data for all properties of the entity type.
- The column names in the result set must match the column names that
  properties are mapped to. Note this is different from EF6.x where
  property/column mapping was ignored for raw SQL queries and result
  set column names had to match the property names.
- The SQL query cannot contain related data. However, in many cases you
  can compose on top of the query using the Include operator to return
  related data (see Including related data).

[**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

You can use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) liberary for raw sql or use Linq query.

Comment: thank you for the tip that looks cleaner but still just getting [] as my result

Comment: change answer, change sql query

Comment: I got this generic error not sure what it means same thing on both results System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
  Class=15
  HResult=-2146232060
  LineNumber=1
  Message=Incorrect syntax near 'PD'.
  Number=102
  Procedure=""
StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

Comment: it says it is incorrect syntax near pd and that it happens on line 33 which is the first select line I have no clue this query runs fine in sql server

Comment: so what I did was I created a view in my database with this query then I just made models for the view and that works sorry for all the trouble but  I am going to mark your answer as correct. Do you know the correct sytax of how I would do this with just EF?

Comment: You can use Dapper liberary for raw sql or use Linq query.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your `where` clause here:

```
Where(x => x.MeterId != "HOGC%")
```

...to be like this:

```
Where(x => !x.MeterId.Startswith("HOGC"))
```

This will act like the `NOT LIKE` in SQL (due to the `!` operator).